# Create TermStore (SPServiceApplicationProxy) Programmatically

Tags: development, sharepoint-foundation, managed-metadata, term-store

Is it possible to create a new custom TermStore Programmatically?
something like

```
SPServiceProxy proxy = SPFarm.Local.ServiceProxies.Where(s => s.GetType().Name.Equals("MetadataWebServiceProxy")).FirstOrDefault();

        SPServiceApplicationProxy spap = SPServiceApplicationProxy("MY Managed Metadata Service");

        proxy.ApplicationProxies.Add();
```

but SPServiceApplicationProxy is a abstract class and is impossible to crate an instance of it.
I know that there is a way to do it in PowerShell but I want to do it in .net.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few posts showing programmatic development of metadata services, term stores, groups & sets -

- [Programmatically Provision Term Store](http://blog.robgarrett.com/2011/04/14/programmatically-provision-term-store/) (shows provisioning the metadata service)
- [Brief Introduction to Enterprise Metadata Management for SharePoint 2010 Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee832800.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but no one of those links is the answer for my problem.

Comment: even the ProvisionMetadataService() method about half-way down the first link (Programmatically Provision Term Store) ?

Comment: no even the ProvisionMetadataService() method, because it does not create any new Meta Data Service.